# Stronglifts 5x5- How can I catch up on weak dead lift and bench?

Tags: strength-training, squats, stronglifts, deadlifts, bench-press

I've started stronglifts 5x5 about 7 weeks ago. I have started out with a completely empty bar (20kgs) and moved up to the following:

Squat 105Kg, Deadlift 102.5Kg, Bench 62.5Kg, OH Press 55Kg, Row 65Kg

A couple of weeks back I stopped for a week and my progression got screwed up and I ended up with a bigger squat and a fairly weak bench. How can I safely catch up on those two lifts?

Comment: I've been also told to keep going as is because it will eventually all balance out. I.e. achieving a more balanced ratio of lifts.

Comment: You are still on beginners gain, based on your progression. Keep going with 5lb addition and you will reach a point where your lifts would be DL > SQ > BP > BR > OHP.

Comment: @PravinCG Awesome, so it will balance out eventually.

Comment: Yes thats correct. However I would advise to ensure you perfect your form else you will start hitting wall once you close in on 1.5X your Body weight.

Answer (score 3):

It's OK to have a bigger squat than the other lifts, and it's one of the best exercises anyway.

I've been doing 5x5 for more than a year now, and my lifts are exactly as PravinCG said : DL > SQ > BP > BR > OHP.
But I did not follow exactly the plan : I added 5kg for the deadlift until I reached 160kg (instead of 2.5kg after 100kg), otherwise I guess my deadlift would be closer to my squat.

Don't try to catch up, be humble, and don't hesitate to drop weight when you miss a few sessions. When I miss a week I drop the weights as many sessions I missed, it's just a way to make sure your form is perfect, because let's be honest : when you add 2.5kg to your best lift every time, at some point your form won't be as good as before. Even if my 5x5 curve is sometimes flat, I warm up heavier than a lot of guys in the gym, so don't worry about catching up : take your time, you'll be strong.